# Error with launch.js debugging Parse-Server in Visual Studio Code

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, vscode-debugger

i am trying to fix an error in parse-server when signing up using Facebook. I try to save PFUser after signed up but fails with `error 206 - cannot modify user`
This happens when `verifyUserEmails` is set to true. I have opened [PR](https://ind01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fparse-community%2Fparse-server%2Fpull%2F8740&data=05%7C01%7Cashishn%40TechMahindra.com%7Cf2ccf8858cc442c14b8008dbb2b9ba09%7Cedf442f5b9944c86a131b42b03a16c95%7C0%7C0%7C638300283037284009%7CUnknown%7CTWFpbGZsb3d8eyJWIjoiMC4wLjAwMDAiLCJQIjoiV2luMzIiLCJBTiI6Ik1haWwiLCJXVCI6Mn0%3D%7C3000%7C%7C%7C&sdata=MsleoEx%2BJEnYAzihhRrypwXvk5MzH8%2F14dnsAc%2FGpjg%3D&reserved=0) and added a failing test and was asked to debug further to identify error source.

I need help with launch.js for VS Code to use my index.js that has all required options to debug.

I tried options like below but getting errors.

```
"configurations": [
     
       {
           "type": "node",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Launch Program",
           "skipFiles": [
               "<node_internals>/**"
           ],
           "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/parse-server",
           "args": [
             "${workspaceFolder}/parse-server-config.json"
           ],
           "outFiles": [
             "${workspaceFolder}/build/cloud/**/*.js"                                      
           ]
       }
   ]
```

this is parse-server-config.json but get Error: ApiMailAdapter: API callback is not a function.

```
{
  "appId": "myAppId",
  "masterKey": "masterkey",
  "appName": "app",
  "cloud": "./cloud/main",
  "databaseURI": "mongodb://192.168.1.2:27017/db",
  "push": {
    "ios": {
        "pfx": "certs/ApplePush.p12",
        "passphrase": "",
        "topic": "com.a.b",
        "production": "false"
    }
},
  "auth": {
    "facebook": {
      "appIds": "[xxxxxx]"
    },
    "apple": {
      "clientId": "com.a.b"
    }
  },
  "verifyUserEmails": "true",
  "preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail": "true",
  "publicServerURL": "http://192.168.1.2:1337/parse",
  "emailAdapter": {
    "module": "parse-server-api-mail-adapter",
    "options": {
      "sender": "sender@example.com",
      "domain": "something.com",
      "apiKey": "mykey-mykey-mykey-mykey-mykey-mykey",
      "templates": {
        "passwordResetEmail": {
          "subjectPath": "public_html/password_reset_email_subject.txt",
          "textPath": "public_html/password_reset_email.txt",
          "htmlPath": "public_html/password_reset_email.html"
        },
        "verificationEmail": {
          "subjectPath": "public_html/verification_email_subject.txt",
          "textPath": "public_html/verification_email.txt",
          "htmlPath": "public_html/verification_email.html"
        },
        "accountDelete": {
          "subjectPath": "public_html/account_delete_subject.txt",
          "textPath": "public_html/account_delete.txt",
          "htmlPath": "public_html/account_delete.html"
        },
        "requestEmail":  {
          "subjectPath": "public_html/request_email_subject.txt",
          "textPath": "public_html/request_email.txt",
          "htmlPath": "public_html/request_email.html"
        }
      },
      "apiCallback":"" **//how to specify this**
      
    }
    }
  }
```

Also tried this but get `Uncaught Error Error: Cannot find module /path/to/index.js`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/parse-server ${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
            "args": [
            ],
            "outFiles": [
              "${workspaceFolder}/build/cloud/**/*.js"                                      
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```